# Parse JSON jq return only keys not values

Tags: json, bash, data-processing, jsonparser

lets say I have this:

https://api.apis.guru/v2/specs/adyen.com/CheckoutService/64/openapi.json

and I want to grab:

```
/orders
/orders/cancel
/originKeys
/paymentLinks
/paymentLinks/{linkId}
/paymentMethods
/paymentMethods/balance
/paymentSession
/payments
/payments/details
/payments/result
```

I want to do that on an elegant way, just grabbing the paths, what I am doing is this ugly workaround, that doesn't work well with some apis:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0" -ks "https://api.apis.guru/v2/specs/adyen.com/CheckoutService/64/openapi.json"  | jq -r '.paths' | grep "/" | grep "{" | egrep -iv "microsoft|amz|application/json|application/jwt|\*|text/xml|text/plain|application/|multipart/form-data|text/html" | cut -d "\"" -f 2
```

Comment: Can you use `jq`?

Comment: Can you provide a (Small!) representative JSON object and what you want to extract from it instead of expecting people to download a large random file?

Comment: Really easy for [tag:xidel]: `xidel -s "<your-json-url>" -e '$json/map:keys(paths)'`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `jq`:

```sh
$ jq -r '.paths | keys | .[]' openapi.json
/orders
/orders/cancel
/originKeys
/paymentLinks
/paymentLinks/{linkId}
/paymentMethods
/paymentMethods/balance
/paymentSession
/payments
/payments/details
/payments/result
```

In your case, you'd want to pipe your `curl` output to `jq` instead of using a file, of course.

The import bits compared to your use of `jq` is piping the `.paths` array to `keys` and that to `.[]` to get one element per line instead of a JSON array, and `-r` to avoid printing each line as a JSON string complete with quote marks.

Comment: Dude, that worked, really, epic man, I owe you one ;)